# Drawing arrows in contours

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, contour

I have drawn this contour in Latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\center
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]

% Realachse
    \draw[->] (-12,0) -- (12,0) node[right] {$\text{Re}$};
    
    % Imaginärachse
    \draw[->] (0,-12) -- (0,12) node[above] {$\text{Im}$};
    
    % Beschriftungen
    %\node at (2.2,0) {Realachse};
    %\node at (0,2.2) {Imaginärachse};



\newcommand\g{4}
\newcommand\T{10}
\newcommand\e{0.5}
\newcommand\Rp{1}
\newcommand\Ip{2}
\newcommand\ly{(\T-\Ip-\e)}
\coordinate (A) at (\g,\T);
\coordinate (B) at (-\T+\Rp,\Ip+\e);
\coordinate (C) at (\Rp,\Ip+\e);
\coordinate (D) at (\Rp,\Ip-\e);
\coordinate (E) at (-\T+\Rp,\Ip-\e);
\coordinate (F) at (\g,-\T);

\tikzset
  {decoration=
     {markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}
     },
   plain/.style={line width=0.8pt},
   arrow/.style={plain,postaction=decorate}
  }


\draw (A) -- (F) ;
\draw (B) -- (C);
\draw (D) -- (E);
\draw (\Rp,\Ip+\e) arc (90:-90:\e);
\draw (\g,\T) arc(90:180:\T cm+\Rp cm +\g cm - 2 cm and \T cm - \Ip cm -\e cm);
\draw (\g,-\T) arc(-90:-180:\T cm +\Rp cm +\g cm - 2 cm and \T cm + \Ip cm -\e cm);

\node at (\Rp cm - 5 cm,\Ip cm + 1.1 cm ) {$H^+$};
\node at (\Rp cm - 5 cm,\Ip cm - 1.1 cm ) {$H^-$};
\node at (\Rp cm + 1.3 cm,\Ip  cm ) {$\Omega_1$};
\node at (\Rp cm - 6 cm,\T  cm - 1 cm) {$\Gamma^+$};
\node at (\Rp cm - 6 cm,-\T  cm + 2 cm) {$\Gamma^-$};
\node at (\g cm + 1.5 cm,\T cm ) {$\gamma+iT$};
\node at (\g cm + 1.5 cm,-\T cm ) {$\gamma-iT$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It works perfectly well. However,

> **I'd like to add arrows (1) in the middle of each H^+ and H^- line (2) in the middle of the ellipses Gamma+ and Gamma- (3) and two arrows
> on the right line from gamma-iT to gamma+iT (so that the line is
> divided by three equal parts through the arrow.)**

Also the direction of the arrows is important, they should be positively oriented - meaning the interior of the contour should be left of the direction of the path.

---

With the following, different contour I somehow managed to draw the arrows as I'd like them as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
% Realachse
    \draw[->] (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$\text{Re}$};
    
    % Imaginärachse
    \draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,4) node[above] {$\text{Im}$};
    
    % Beschriftungen
    %\node at (2.2,0) {Realachse};
    %\node at (0,2.2) {Imaginärachse};

\tikzset
  {decoration=
     {markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}
     },
   plain/.style={line width=0.8pt},
   arrow/.style={plain,postaction=decorate}
  }


\newcommand\g{2}
\newcommand\T{6}
\newcommand\e{0.5}
\newcommand\Rp{1}
\newcommand\Ip{2}
\newcommand\ly{(\T-\Ip-\e)}
\coordinate (A) at (\g,\T);
\coordinate (B) at (-\T+\Rp,\Ip+\e);
\coordinate (C) at (\Rp,\Ip+\e);
\coordinate (D) at (\Rp,\Ip-\e);
\coordinate (E) at (-\T+\Rp,\Ip-\e);
\coordinate (F) at (\g,-\T);
\draw [arrow] (B) -- (C);
\draw [arrow] (D) -- (E);
\draw [line width=0.8pt] (\Rp,\Ip+\e) arc (90:270:\e);
\draw [line width=0.8pt] (-\T+\Rp,\Ip+\e) arc (90:270:\e);

\node at (\Rp cm - 5 cm,\Ip cm + 1.1 cm ) {$H^+$};
\node at (\Rp cm - 5 cm,\Ip cm - 1.1 cm ) {$H^-$};
\node at (\Rp cm - 7.1 cm,\Ip  cm ) {$\Omega_2$};
\node at (\Rp cm + 0.3 cm,\Ip  cm ) {$\Omega_3$};


%\draw  [dash pattern=on 3pt off 2pt] (\Rp,\Ip ) -- (\Rp+4,\Ip );
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Die Kontur $\mathcal R$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In this case the arrows are negatively oriented and that's good. But how can I take the following arrow making command I used in the second contour

```
\tikzset
      {decoration=
         {markings,
          mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}
         },
       plain/.style={line width=0.8pt},
       arrow/.style={plain,postaction=decorate}
      }
```

and apply it to my first contour? My difficulties are (1) direction of the arrows (2) that the arrows also are in the middle of ellipses and not only straight lines (3) and how I can make two arrows on one straight line (in this case from gamma-iT to gamma+iT).

I've researched on the internet a lot but always if I've found a solution it meant I had to sacrifice another. (E.g. when I got the direction, the arrows were no longer centered.)

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks I forgot to add them. Now it should work better.

Comment: Why is my question being downvoted? I showed everything I did. I answered comments. I stated my question clearly. So what's the reason?

Comment: Can you add the missing amsmath package to your code and add a sketch exactly how the image should look like?

Answer (score 2):

After editing your question, regardless that it is still not compilable, is a bit more clear, what is your problem.

For adding arrows you need to add to drawing commands of all segments option `postaction={decorate}`.

I suspect, that you expect that all arrows should have the same direction (contra clockwise?). Do I'm right? If yes, you need to rewrote drawing command for red segments, for the first I already change direction of drawing:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % missed in your MWE

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]

% Realachse
    \draw[->] (-12,0) -- (12,0) node[right] {$\text{Re}$};
% Imaginärachse
    \draw[->] (0,-12) -- (0,12) node[above] {$\text{Im}$};

\newcommand\g{4}
\newcommand\T{10}
\newcommand\e{0.5}
\newcommand\Rp{1}
\newcommand\Ip{2}
\newcommand\ly{(\T-\Ip-\e)}
\coordinate (A) at (\g,\T);
\coordinate (B) at (-\T+\Rp,\Ip+\e);
\coordinate (C) at (\Rp,\Ip+\e);
\coordinate (D) at (\Rp,\Ip-\e);
\coordinate (E) at (-\T+\Rp,\Ip-\e);
\coordinate (F) at (\g,-\T);

\tikzset
  {decoration=
     {markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}
     },
   plain/.style={line width=0.8pt},
   arrow/.style={plain,postaction=decorate}
  }


\draw[postaction={decorate}] (F) -- (A) ;
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (B) -- (C);
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (D) -- (E);
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (\Rp,\Ip+\e) arc (90:-90:\e);
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (\g,\T) arc(90:180:\T cm+\Rp cm +\g cm - 2 cm and \T cm - \Ip cm -\e cm);
\draw[postaction={decorate}, red] (\g,-\T) arc(-90:-180:\T cm +\Rp cm +\g cm - 2 cm and \T cm + \Ip cm -\e cm);

\node at (\Rp cm - 5 cm,\Ip cm + 1.1 cm ) {$H^+$};
\node at (\Rp cm - 5 cm,\Ip cm - 1.1 cm ) {$H^-$};
\node at (\Rp cm + 1.3 cm,\Ip  cm ) {$\Omega_1$};
\node at (\Rp cm - 6 cm,\T  cm - 1 cm) {$\Gamma^+$};
\node at (\Rp cm - 6 cm,-\T  cm + 2 cm) {$\Gamma^-$};
\node at (\g cm + 1.5 cm,\T cm ) {$\gamma+iT$};
\node at (\g cm + 1.5 cm,-\T cm ) {$\gamma-iT$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

BTW, it seems that you like to draw integration pat by which you exclude function poles. Complex poles always appear in conjugate complex pairs ...

**Addendum:**
After iteration of comments and added image what id desired goal, seems to main problem how to draw (integration) path.

MWE below is is written from scratch, hopefully sufficient clear that code doesn't need additional comments. Coordinates as determined as points on circle with radius 90mm (it can be change), lines are than drawn on on correct order from coordinate A in counter clockwise direction back to node A:

Let me emphasize, that code is now quite shorter and far more clear:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,
                ext.arrows
                }
\usepackage{mathtools}    % missed in your MWE
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,
arr/.style = {-Straight Barb},
->-/.style = {decoration = {markings,
                mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Centered Stealth}}},
              postaction=decorate, semithick, color=red,
              line cap=round,
              },
lbl/.style = {auto=right, text=black, midway}
                    ]
% axis
\draw[->] (-10,0) -- (9,0) node[right] {$\re$};
\draw[->] (0,-10) -- (0,10) node[above] {$\im$};

% coordinates, determines by polar coordinates on circle
\path   (0,0) -- (4.5,0) coordinate (A);
\path   (0,0) -- ( 60:9) coordinate[label=right:$\gamma + iT$] (B)
              -- (162:9) coordinate (C)
              -- (170:9) coordinate (D)
              -- (300:9) coordinate[label=right:$\gamma - iT$] (E);
\draw[->-] (A) -- (B);
\draw[->-] (B) arc (60:162:9) node[lbl] {$\Gamma^+$};
\draw[->-] (C) -- ++ (10,0)   node[lbl,swap] {$H^-$}
                            coordinate (c);
%
\draw[->-] (c) arc (90:-90:6.1mm) node[lbl, swap] {$\Omega_1$};
%
\draw[->-] (c |- D) -- (D)    node[lbl,swap] {$H^-$};
\draw[->-] (D) arc (170:300:9) node[lbl] {$\Gamma^-$};
\draw[->-] (E) -- (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I have managed to do. However (1) the arrow of the Gamma-Minus path is wrongly oriented - it should point in the other direction (also I don't know why it's read). (2) I don't need an arrow on Omega_1 contour and (3) Is it possible to make two arrows on the line from [gamma-iT,gamma+iT]? One in the middle of the lower half-plane and one in the middle of the upper half plane. *But otherwise it's approaches the contour I'm looking for.*

Comment: @vitamind, sorry, your claims not hold. Your MWE doesn't generate any arrows, so you not manage anything what is done in my answer. To clarify, what you after, please add hand drawn image of desired result. Your question is still unclear, even more after your comments. One sketch=1000 words ...

Comment: I'm sorry you are right, I forgot to include my version with the arrows in my question and a sketch is indeed better. I added one. My three points are (1)The arrow on the Gamma-Minus path should go into the other direction (2) for Omega_1 path doesn't need an arrow (3) two arrows on straight line from gamma-iT to gamma+iT as in the sketch. Thanks

Comment: @vitamind, of course I'm right (since I'm full of C vitamins by which I treat the flu catch last week) :-). Thank you for the sketch. According to it you also need to rewrite your code: interchange start and the end of red segments (as I stated in my answer), divide segment A-F into two parts. Sorry, but your code is not entirely clear to me, si will not interfere in it,

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know how I can change the direction of the red section without messing up the code. (I'm new to tikz). Also I know it sounds stupid but please I really need your help, it needs to be done today for my big work and I have so much other things to do... I'll try to do it nonetheless, but I probably won't succeed (especially with the orientation of the red part)

Comment: @vitamind, <now we discover your (main) problem. This means that someone should rewrite your code (almost from scratch or you need to define tow two functions for drawing arrows. Since here is time for slip, I will see, what I can be simpler to do. BTW, for nicer arrows see `ext.arrows` library provided by package `tikz-ext` package.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the main problem. How can I change orientation of \draw[postaction={decorate}] (\g,-\T) arc(-90:-180:\T cm +\Rp cm +\g cm - 2 cm and \T cm + \Ip cm -\e cm)?

Comment: I did it, thanks so much!